# How to send mail as outlook pro account in outlook free?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, webmail

I have a student mail at my university which is setup to redirect all incoming emails to my old hotmail/outlook free account. I also want to be able to send emails from my free account, as the student account (without using masquerade). The university uses the microsoft lisam suite and outlook free apparently doesn't find their smtp server.

the guide on lisam outlook says this:

```
SMTP-settings
Server name: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: TLS
```

but it still cannot connect to the smtp server. It seems really weird that outlook cannot connect to their own servers...

What have I done wrong? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The server name you attempted to use is only valid if your using Office365 and if you have a free Outlook.com account then that isn't the case.  Have you asked your university what the SMTP server is?  **We are unable to tell you what it is.**

Comment: Those settings are from the lisam website. They even told me that I had to check specifically for our accounts and so I did.